# Managing workflows with nodejs

Tags: google-workflows

I am trying to use nodejs to manage my workflows instead of using the console. The createWorkflow method returns a 200 code but I cannot find it in the console or when listing it. Any idea what is missing? the typescript typedef has too many partials to be useful on what is needed and what is not. In the code below the list method returns correctly the workflow names I created in the console which proves that I use the parent params correctly I guess. However when I call the create method with the name of a new workflow and some code, I get this this back and a return code of 200 which should mean it was successful but can't find it. Also trying to execute it returns a not found.

**return value:**

```
{
  "_events": {},
  "_eventsCount": 2,
  "completeListeners": 0,
  "hasActiveListeners": false,
  "latestResponse": {
    "name": "projects/xxxxx/locations/us-central1/operations/operation-1607572432499-5b6141fca342d-32b153bf-bfce0551",
    "metadata": {
      "type_url": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.workflows.v1beta.OperationMetadata",
      "value": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
          10,
          12,
          8,
          208,
          183,
          198,
          254,
          5,
          16,
          236,
          212,
          251,
          180,
          2,
          26,
          76,
          112,
          114,
          111,
          106,
          101,
          99,
          116,
          115,
          47,
          98,
          117,
          116,
          116,
          101,
          114,
          102,
          108,
          121,
          45,
          105,
          116,
          45,
          55,
          102,
          55,
          55,
          98,
          47,
          108,
          111,
          99,
          97,
          116,
          105,
          111,
          110,
          115,
          47,
          117,
          115,
          45,
          99,
          101,
          110,
          116,
          114,
          97,
          108,
          49,
          47,
          119,
          111,
          114,
          107,
          102,
          108,
          111,
          119,
          115,
          47,
          116,
          101,
          115,
          116,
          95,
          119,
          111,
          114,
          107,
          102,
          108,
          111,
          119,
          95,
          118,
          49,
          34,
          6,
          99,
          114,
          101,
          97,
          116,
          101,
          42,
          6,
          118,
          49,
          98,
          101,
          116,
          97
        ]
      }
    },
    "done": false
  },
  "name": "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxx/locations/us-central1/operations/operation-1607572432499-5b6141fca342d-32b153bf-bfce0551",
  "done": false,
  "longrunningDescriptor": {
    "operationsClient": {
      "auth": {
        "checkIsGCE": true,
        "jsonContent": null,
        "cachedCredential": {
          "_events": {},
          "_eventsCount": 0,
          "transporter": {},
          "credentials": {
            "access_token": "ya29.c.KpcB6AdCAMGMr_FqY7veU-uQTAP2cenQDWOh3Msaw-CPjdodjeYKAEf7lw-m1joxmam06_4QgRJ5Atnlpcm7db37CAi0lz4LS5_KPkvaodE6oefkDChOly92BxyCfaJClrKqklcEbSt1yg-2iVwngXccgwtdko9sbM4UeUihNPYScdGY0bGT484x7Ai6e2vtAfZMC2r-DqGE-g",
            "token_type": "Bearer",
            "expiry_date": 1607573907456,
            "refresh_token": "compute-placeholder"
          },
          "certificateCache": {},
          "certificateExpiry": null,
          "certificateCacheFormat": "PEM",
          "refreshTokenPromises": {},
          "eagerRefreshThresholdMillis": 300000,
          "forceRefreshOnFailure": false,
          "serviceAccountEmail": "default",
          "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
          ]
        },
        "_cachedProjectId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "defaultScopes": [
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
        ],
        "_getDefaultProjectIdPromise": {}
      },
      "innerApiCalls": {},
      "descriptor": {
        "listOperations": {
          "requestPageTokenField": "pageToken",
          "responsePageTokenField": "nextPageToken",
          "resourceField": "operations"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "result": null,
  "metadata": {
    "createTime": {
      "seconds": "1607572432",
      "nanos": 647948908
    },
    "target": "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxx/locations/us-central1/workflows/test_workflow_v1",
    "verb": "create",
    "apiVersion": "v1beta"
  },
  "backoffSettings": {
    "initialRetryDelayMillis": 100,
    "retryDelayMultiplier": 1.3,
    "maxRetryDelayMillis": 60000,
    "initialRpcTimeoutMillis": null,
    "rpcTimeoutMultiplier": null,
    "maxRpcTimeoutMillis": null,
    "totalTimeoutMillis": null
  },
  "_callOptions": {
    "timeout": 30000,
    "retry": {
      "retryCodes": [],
      "backoffSettings": {
        "initialRetryDelayMillis": 100,
        "retryDelayMultiplier": 1.3,
        "maxRetryDelayMillis": 60000,
        "initialRpcTimeoutMillis": 60000,
        "rpcTimeoutMultiplier": 1,
        "maxRpcTimeoutMillis": 60000,
        "totalTimeoutMillis": 600000
      }
    },
    "autoPaginate": true,
    "otherArgs": {
      "headers": {
        "x-goog-request-params": "parent=projects%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxx%2Flocations%2Fus-central1"
      }
    },
    "bundleOptions": null,
    "isBundling": true,
    "apiName": "google.cloud.workflows.v1beta.Workflows"
  }
}
```

** code: **

```
engine: ExecutionsClient;
  builder: WorkflowsClient;

  location = 'us-central1';
  projectId: string;

  constructor() {
    this.engine = new ExecutionsClient();
    this.builder = new WorkflowsClient();
    this.projectId = serviceAccount.project_id;
  }


 async list(): Promise<any> {
    console.log (`list workflows`);

    const [ resp ] = await this.builder.listWorkflows({
      parent: this.builder.locationPath(this.projectId, this.location),
    });

    console.log (`listWorkflow: ${JSON.stringify(resp)}`);
    return resp;
  }

  async create(name: string, code: string): Promise<any> {

    console.log (`creating workflow named: ${name}`);

    const [ resp ] = await this.builder.createWorkflow({
      parent: this.builder.locationPath(this.projectId, this.location),
      workflow: {
        sourceContents: code,
      },
      workflowId: name
    });

    console.log (`createWorkflow: ${JSON.stringify(resp)}`);
    return resp;
  }



 async execute(name: string): Promise<any> {
    const [resp] = await this.engine.createExecution({
      parent: this.engine.workflowPath(this.projectId, this.location, name),
    });

    return resp;
  }
```

Comment: which endpoint you are trying to call? Is it create Workflow or create Execution?

Comment: Create workflow

Comment: If you are getting a status 200 but the workflow isn't being created, that Could be a problem with Workflows itself. I would recommend you to reach out to Google in Their [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) if that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting the source for google-cloud/workflows I found where the problem was. createWorkflow is what they call a long operation and is actually 2 successive promises

```
const [operation] = await client.createWorkflow(request);
const [response] = await operation.promise();
```